# Make a Tkinter Gui using classes

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I want to create a GUI in a class that can create pages using another class that creates frames and widgets. The pages are set using a class for them. I want to be able to GUI to be able to switch between the different set of pages. I can't create a button for the class of the Login_page that with switch the Login_page with the class of the Sign_page.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class maingui:
    def __init__(self,title, geometry,):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)
        self.pageshow = Login_Page(self.root)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def changepage(self, page):
        self.page = page
        if self.page == 0:
            self.pageshow = Login_Page(self.root)
        if self.page == 1:
            self.pageshow = Sign_Page(self.root)
        self.root.mainloop()



class createWindow:
    def __init__(self,root, title, geometry,):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)
        self.root.mainloop()
    
class createFrame:
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()
        print('c')
    def clear(self):
        pass
    def createlabel(self,message,postion = None):
        self.message =message
        self.postion = postion
        self.label= Label(self.frame, text =self.message)
        if self.postion == None:
            self.label.pack()
            print('a')
        else:
            print('b')
    def createbutton(self, text, command):
        self.text = text
        self.command = command
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text = self.text, command =self.command)

class Login_Page():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = createFrame(self.window)
        self.frame.createlabel("Hello World")
        self.frame.createbutton("1",maingui.changepage(self.window,1))
class Sign_Page():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = createFrame(self.window)
        self.frame.createlabel("Hello ")       

maingui = maingui("Rpg", "400x400")
```

Edit: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'root'
On line

```
if self.page == 1:
      self.pageshow = Sign_Page(self.root)
```

On this line

```
self.frame.createbutton("1",maingui.changepage(self.window,1))
```

I try to create a button using a class and the command is from a different class.

Comment: I edit it to include the specific problem.

Comment: Suggest to make `maingui` inherit from `Tk`.

Comment: as for me you have too many `mainloop()` - found 3: in `maingui.__init__()`, in `maingui.changepage()`, in `createWindow` - but `tkintner` should use only one `mainloop()`

Comment: always put full erro message (starting at word "Tracebak") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are otheruseful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass `self.root` (instance of `Tk()`) of `maingui` class to `Login_Page` and assign it to `self.window`. Then `self.window` is used in `maingui.changepage(self.window, 1)` inside `Login_Page` class. Since you use class name to access `changepage()`, `self.window` will be treat as the `self` argument of `changepage()` and used in `Sign_Page(self.root)`.  That means you want to access the attribute `root` of `self` (instance of `Tk()`) but `Tk` does not have attribute `root`.

Suggest to make `maingui` interit from `Tk` instead of creating it inside `__init__()`.

Below is an updated example based on yours:

```py
from tkinter import *
#import random

class maingui(Tk):
    def __init__(self, title, geometry):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(geometry)
        self.pageshow = Login_Page(self)
    def changepage(self, page):
        self.page = page
        if self.page == 0:
            self.pageshow = Login_Page(self)
        if self.page == 1:
            self.pageshow = Sign_Page(self)

class createFrame:
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()
        print('c')
    def clear(self):
        pass
    def createlabel(self,message,postion = None):
        self.message =message
        self.postion = postion
        self.label= Label(self.frame, text =self.message)
        if self.postion == None:
            self.label.pack()
            print('a')
        else:
            print('b')
    def createbutton(self, text, command):
        self.text = text
        self.command = command
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text = self.text, command =self.command)
        self.button.pack() ###

class Login_Page():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = createFrame(self.window)
        self.frame.createlabel("Hello World")
        ###self.frame.createbutton("1", maingui.changepage(self.window, 1)) ###
        self.frame.createbutton("1", lambda: self.window.changepage(1)) ###

class Sign_Page():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = createFrame(self.window)
        self.frame.createlabel("Hello ")       

maingui = maingui("Rpg", "400x400") 
maingui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code, I would also suggest you read and practice classes before moving further.

(*Note*: I have not defined your clear method or added any new method, I have just corrected your existing code and rectified your error. you may further if you want, define your clear method and destroy your widgets).

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class maingui:
    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry):

        self.root = root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)
        self.pageshow = Login_Page(self, self.root)
      
    def changepage(self, page):
        self.page = page
        
        if self.page == 0:
            self.pageshow = Login_Page(self, self.root)

        if self.page == 1:
            self.pageshow = Sign_Page(self, self.root)

class createWindow:
    def __init__(self,root, title, geometry):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)
      
class createFrame:
    def __init__(self, parent, window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.label = Label(self.frame)
        self.button = Button(self.frame)
        self.parent = parent
        

    def clear(self):
        pass

    def createlabel(self,message,postion = None):
        self.message =message
        self.postion = postion
        self.label.config(text=self.message)
        
        if self.postion == None:
            self.label.pack()
        
        else:
           pass


    def createbutton(self, text='Login', cmd=0):
        self.text = text

        self.button.configure(text=self.text, command=lambda :self.parent.changepage(cmd))
        self.button.pack()

class Login_Page():
    def __init__(self, parent, window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = createFrame(parent, self.window)
        self.frame.createlabel("Hello World bye")
        self.frame.createbutton("Welcome", 1)


class Sign_Page():
    def __init__(self, parent, window):
        self.window = window
        self.frame = createFrame(parent, self.window)
        self.frame.createlabel("Hello ")       


def main():
    root = Tk()
    maingui(root, "Rpg", "400x400")
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

**update**: here is a way you can switch between pages(in my case you can switch between the sign-up and login page). click on login it will direct you to sign-up and vice-versa.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class maingui:
    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry):

        self.root = root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)
        self.pageshow = Login_Page(self, self.root)
      
    def changepage(self, page):
        self.page = page
        
        if self.page == 0:
            #del self.pageshow
            self.pageshow = Login_Page(self, self.root)

        if self.page == 1:
            #del self.pageshow
            self.pageshow = Sign_Page(self, self.root)


class Login_Page:
    def __init__(self, parent, window):
        
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.frame = Frame(window)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.welcm_lbl = Label(self.frame, text='welcome')
        self.welcm_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.name_lbl = Label(self.frame, text='name:')
        self.name_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.name_entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.sbt = Button(self.frame, text='login', command=self.clicked)
        self.sbt.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def clicked(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.parent.changepage(1)
        

class Sign_Page():
    def __init__(self, parent, window):

        self.parent = parent
        
        self.frame = Frame(window)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.welcm_lbl = Label(self.frame, text='welcome sign-up')
        self.welcm_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.name_lbl = Label(self.frame, text='name:')
        self.name_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.name_entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.sbt = Button(self.frame, text='sign-up', command=self.clicked)
        self.sbt.grid(row=2, column=1)      

    def clicked(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.parent.changepage(0)
        
    
def main():
    root = Tk()
    maingui(root, "Rpg", "400x400")
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: as for me you have too many `mainloop()` - found `3`: in `main()`, in `changepage()`, in `createWindow` - but `tkintner` should use only one `mainloop()`

Comment: @furas yep, I forgot to remove them thx for pointing.